# Could I be resident in both Belgium and Ireland?

Tags: resident-permit

Currently, I am a Non-EU working in Belgium. I have a long relationship with a EU citizen. She got a great opportunity and she has moved to Ireland. We were living together for a while in Belgium and I was thinking to visit her very frequently as I can work remotely. Due to the Covid situation, tourist visas are not accepted yet. So we are thinking of requesting from the Ireland government the De Facto Relationship visa. My question is: as I am an employee in Belgium and I cannot leave the work yet (still 2 years to finish my project) but I would like to stay with her, could I have at the same time 2 residencies from two different EU countries?

Comment: What do you mean by ‘stay with her’? Visit her regularly/frequently? Live in Ireland and work remotely for your Belgian employer?

Comment: Since I have to finish the project, should be 2-3 in Ireland/ 1 week in Belgium. In this case should be living in Ireland and working remotely in Belgium.

Comment: "Resident of Ireland working for a company in Belgium" seems closer to describe your situation. You plan to spend majority of your time in Ireland. Better is to ask if you can, as resident of Ireland, be employed by a company in Belgium?